# Design a Parser for multiple command list from Json file

Tags: c++

Would love some opinions on this problem I'm trying to workout. I'm trying to improve my OO experience and fully leverage C++'s polymorphic capabilities. I'm trying to write some code for a basic command parser. The commands comes from a Json multiple lines file.

As shown here:

```
{"command_name":"vkGetDeviceQueue","call_index":8,"threadId":3,"return_value":"void","parameters":{"device":"0x0000000000000005","queueFamilyIndex":0,"queueIndex":0,"pQueue":"0x0000000000000006"}}
{"command_name":"vkCreateFence","call_index":9,"threadId":3,"return_value":"VK_SUCCESS","parameters":{"device":"0x0000000000000005","pCreateInfo":{"sType":"VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FENCE_CREATE_INFO","flags":"0x00000001","pNext":null},"pAllocator":null,"pFence":"0x0000000000000010"}}
```

sample file of the JSON

As you know the API can have lots of API Calls. I would like to proceed on an OOP way.. probablly a factory pattern would help ? that's my guess.. but don't know how to proceed with a good design. I would like to avoid multiple if statements for each command in the full VULKAN API.

Comment: Not seeing any obvious need for a factory. I would start simple, a `Command` class that is a base class for each of the different commands, one derived class for each actual command, and then a map mapping the command name to each individual command object. There might well be a name for this (frankly I don't pay much attention to patterns, they're mostly obvious or very obscure) but it's not factory.

Comment: @john Can you show me a prototype in an answer please ? plus 1

Comment: @john What should be there in the base class command ? is it an abstract class? How do I instantiate different commands classes without IFs ?

Comment: Yes, I would imagine the base class is abstract. You only need to instantiate each derived command once, when you place it in the map, I'm imagining them as effectively singletons. Then the lookup in the map is what replaces the multiple if statements.

Comment: @john Can you show an example please ? :)

Comment: Sorry no time for a prototype, maybe some one else will oblige, or suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately you can't really avoid if statements, but you can move this logic to e.g. a parser or a Factory if you prefer. Expanding a bit on john's comment, you can have a `Command` class that looks more or less like this:

```
class Command
{
public:
  virtual ~Command() = default;
  void execute() = 0;
};
```

and some entity that allows you to create the superclass objects, like:

```
// or make it a factory class, if you feel it will be better
std::unique_ptr<Command> parseCommand(const SomeJson& j) {  // here come your if/else logic
  if (j["command_name"] == "command1")
  {
    // do some logic to create concrete command and return it; class can be defined in this translation unit, or somewhere else, up to you
    return std::make_unique<CommandOne>(j["command_payload"]);
    // return createCommand1(j["command_payload"]);  // or move it to separate function, it can also be defined in this translation unit, or somewhere else, hidden from the user
  }
  // etc etc ...
}
```

where concrete `CommandXxx` classes can be hidden from your public interfaces. Then in your code you can have:

```
for (auto line : yourInputSplitInLines)
{
  collection.push_back(parseCommand(SomeJson(line)));
}
// and later
for (auto& cmd : collection)
{
  cmd->execute();
}
```

where collection is a container of your choice. It can also be `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Command>>` if you want to have the possibility to look up commands by name.

Comment: Thanks.. Where is CommandXxx is defined ? can you show more please about the logic that should be done ? especially the unordered_map how would I use it ?

Comment: Also what parseCommand(some json) could return what ? can you show more in this place please ?, how come I will write 500s of commands as IF, Else here ?

Comment: but I would have 500 If statements for 500 API Calls.. No solution to that ?

Comment: Well, these are very generic questions and to cover every aspect  I might end up writing a book :) I edited the answer a bit to clarify the command creation. And for the 500 if statements: if every 1 of your 500 commands has unique behavior and unique set of arguments, then yes, in the end you need to write 500 different pieces of logic for that. The good news is that this 500 different functions, or if statements do not need to be visible to the rest of your implementation, it will be hidden behind `parseCommand` facade.

Comment: There are some commands that has the same properties (structure), how would I abstract that in command creation please ?

Comment: This is easy, just think about how to design a superclass for them. Imagine you have some `class VkCreateGenericCommand`, if "Generic" part of the command always has the same set of parameters, you can use the same function to create all commands of this type. Then you need to think about your possible commands and divide them logically.

Comment: Can you add please an example of a VkCreateGenericCommand ?

Comment: @andre_lamothe Fwiw, I was working on the question you now deleted. I just needed more details.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I wanted to edit it and clicked delete, and it's deleted :( will open a new one ?

Comment: Can't you undelete it? (I never tried myself)

Comment: @TedLyngmo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76014599/convert-nolhman-json-c-to-csv
Thanks so much for your caring

Comment: @andre_lamothe I think undeleting the old question that showed your code would have been better. I think the new question will get downvotes. Just update the old question and be specific. Your new question doesn't tell us how to deal with JSON arrays for example since it just has one array with one element and you make that into a `string`. What if there are two elements etc?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I can't undelete the question.. there is no option to that. Yes that's a problem, it should handle multiple arrays...

Comment: Ok, well, I think I will be able to provide a starting point at least. I'm sure you'll need to tweak the answer a bit to fit your intended consumer though, but ... I'll have something ready in ~30 minutes.